# Does the mapping in smart contracts define the ownership of a token?

Tags: blockchain, tokens, nft

Lately became interested in Ethereum. I have some questions which I could not find an exact answer to. Maybe someone can help.

1. Do you "own" an NFT via the mapping in the smart contract? Thus simply the addresses change when "transferred"?
2. When 1. holds true, arent "hacked" cryptocurrencies and nfts basically never truly lost but simply pointing to the wrong address? (I guess that is why forks are a workaround?)
3. When are these functions for transfer/offer of the smart contract called/executed? When the Block is mined by the miner and by every (full) node?
4. Where are the tokens after creation? Are the addresses of the tokens in the smart contract simply not set yet?

Best regards and thanks in advance!
Sunny

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope this sheds some light on your questions:

1. That's right, the ownership of a token is defined in the `_owners` mapping. [Here](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/d3ff81b37f3c773b44dcaf5fda212c7176eef0e2/contracts/token/ERC721/ERC721.sol#L30) is a link to OpenZeppelin's implementation of it.
2. They are pointing at the "hacker's" address, but work as the smart contract is intended to work, so wrong is a strong word. Forking, or restructuring chain data, would solve the issue, but doing so for a simple smart contract would be highly unlikely.
3. Every function execution result is finalised once the miner runs the transaction and includes it in a block.
4. When tokens are minted, they are assigned to an address, might be the caller or some other user that the caller specified. If a token exists, but has no assigned owner, or rather has the owner address set to `0x0` address, this means that it has been burned and shouldn't be able to be assigned to any user.